# dummy filesize after do "cat /dev/null > logfile.log"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, suse

I need to clear the content of an logfile. Then I tryed to use "cat /dev/null > logfile". 
In fact, it works! 
But there is a strange behavior who I can't understand. Immediatelly after clear the file is the size been displayed as 0 bytes, but after a single modification, the size came back to the previous value. With a "du" i can see that this value is wrong. 
Am I doing it right? How can I correct it?

my cat command:

```
jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> ls -lah
-rw-r--r-- 1 jorplov svcusr  10G 2013-11-15 05:18 sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-fsc  2.0G  1.8G   90M  96% /applications/fsc


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> cat /dev/null > sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-fsc  2.0G  365M  1.6G  20% /applications/fsc


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> ls -lah
total 20K
-rw-r--r-- 1 jorplov svcusr    0 2013-11-15 05:25 sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log
```

after a few seconds:

```
jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> ls -lah
-rw-r--r-- 1 jorplov svcusr  10G 2013-11-15 05:26 sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> stat sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log
  File: `sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log'
  Size: 10718153084     Blocks: 32         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 82380       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (30013/ jorplov)   Gid: (21459/  svcusr)
Access: 2013-11-15 05:34:00.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2013-11-15 05:34:12.000000000 +0100
Change: 2013-11-15 05:34:12.000000000 +0100
```

a second try:

```
jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> > sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> stat sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log
  File: `sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 82380       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (30013/ jorplov)   Gid: (21459/  svcusr)
Access: 2013-11-15 05:34:00.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2013-11-15 05:46:55.000000000 +0100
Change: 2013-11-15 05:46:55.000000000 +0100


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> ls -lah
-rw-r--r-- 1 jorplov svcusr    0 2013-11-15 05:46 sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log
```

again, few seconds later:

```
jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> stat sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log
  File: `sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log'
  Size: 10718153546     Blocks: 32         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 82380       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (30013/ jorplov)   Gid: (21459/  svcusr)
Access: 2013-11-15 05:34:00.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2013-11-15 05:53:12.000000000 +0100
Change: 2013-11-15 05:53:12.000000000 +0100


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> ls -lah
-rw-r--r-- 1 jorplov svcusr  10G 2013-11-15 05:53 sagm061_jorplov_startup.log


jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> du -h sagm061_jorplov_startup.log
16K     sagm061_jorplov_startup.log
```

Comment: drop the `cat /dev/null` in `cat /dev/null > something`, use simply `> something`

Comment: I already tried it too, but I got the same result (please see "secound try" on the code above). It seems that the process who is writing the file is doing this.

Comment: Sure, my comment was not meant as an answer, but a general tip to improve your script. @anubhava's answer is spot on, this is just a side note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due the to process that is writing text into this log file.

If the process is writing into logs like this:

```
command > log.txt
```

And you truncate the logs externally then as soon as next line is added by `command` into log it will write it after previous file pointer position and **fill the file with null bytes `\0` from start to that file pointer position**. Therefore size of log file will become same as it was before you truncated the log file.

**Solution:**

However if log is being written as:

```
command >> log.txt
```

That log will be written in "append mode". **In this mode before writing next line it will always move the file pointer to the end of file and that will avoid this situation.** You can truncate the log file anytime.

Comment: i just find out that I have a Java process who is writing this file:`jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> fuser sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log
jorplov  19979     1  0 Sep20 ?        04:17:10 /usr/java/latest/bin/java 

jorplov@sg0080b:/applications/fsc/base/logs> lsof |grep sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log
java      19979    jorplov    1w      REG              253,3 10718154932      82380 /applications/fsc/base/logs/sg0080b_jorplov_startup.log`

Comment: If you change `>` by `>>` in the Java command line it will behave nicely.